# Rust question : Cannot borrow parts of tuple mutably and immutably when tuple is inside a vector

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have tried to execute the following code, but it doesn't compile because "a vector cannot be borrowed as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable".

The problem is that I don't see how error message is relevant. I am borrowing immutably array[1].1 and mutably array[1].0 which don't overlap.

Isn't borrow checker smart enough to see that there is no conflict and non-overlapped parts of tuples are accessed?

```
fn main() {
  //everything is ok when tuple is alone
  let mut pair : (usize, Vec<usize>) = (0, Vec::new());
  println!("{} {:?}", &pair.0, &mut pair.1);

  let mut array : Vec<(usize, Vec<usize>)> 
      = vec![(1, Vec::new()), (2, Vec::new())];
  //everything works till here
  // but the rest doesn't...
  println!("{} {:?}", &array[1].0, &mut array[1].1);
}
```

I am confused : why can I borrow parts of a single tuple mutably and immutably, but cannot do it when tuple is inside a vector.
Is it related to splitting borrows described in Rustonomicon?

And finally, the most important : is there a way to fix this code without separating a vector of tuples into 2 vectors?

While a quick answer to the last question is enough for me, I would appreciate a bit more explanation and also answers to my other questions. And if you have a more idiomatic Rust solution for such problem, that would be great too :)

Thanks in advance for taking your time to help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fails because the indexing operation tries to borrow `array` mutably and immutably at the same time, which isn't allowed.

However, you can borrow *different parts* of a value even mutably at the same time (a "[splitting borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html)"), but to do this Rust has to *know* that they are part of the same value.  It can't figure this out when you index `array` twice.  (Nothing *requires* that `Index` and `IndexMut` return a reference to the same value, nor that they will do so given the same index when called twice, nor that `IndexMut` won't modify any state.)

You can accomplish this by borrowing a particular item once, then reborrowing parts of it:

```
// Borrow mutably from the array once.
let item1 = &mut array[1];

// Reborrow different parts of the item, splitting the mutable borrow above
// into two borrows.
println!("{} {:?}", &item1.0, &mut item1.1);
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14221d49ef339f5b47244846de9b86a6))